# Rotate LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

i want to use vertical ProgressBars. By default they are not available in Android, so i tried to put them in a LinearLayout and rotate it by 90 degrees.
The problem is, the LinearLayout doesn´t resize after the animation, so I tried to put some manual resize into the AnimationListener:

Listener:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    changeBarLayoutBounds();
}
```

...

Activity:

```
private void changeBarLayoutBounds() {
    int newWidth = params.height; // the params I copied before animation
    params.height = params.width
    params.width = newWidth;

    barLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    barLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

This method somehow doensn´t work at all, does anybody have an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom progress bar. [HERE](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/) you can find an example. Just use clip and set gravity to top or bottom and use 9-pathes that could grow vertically. Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the idea of using clipdrawables to create my own progressbars. If i wont be able to find a solution to rotate my layout, i will do it like you suggested. thank you